# Custom Regroup Order

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to reorder a queryset in a Django template using a custom ordering scheme.

This is the template code:

```
{% regroup teams_at_school by season.school_year as teams %}
    <ul id="sport-picker">
        <li class="first"><span>Sports by year</span></li>
            {% for team_grouper in teams|dictsort:"season__school_year" %}
            <li><span>{{ team_grouper.grouper }}<img src="http://hometeam.s3.amazonaws.com/graphics/down-pointer.png"></span>
                <ul class="dropper">
                    {% for team_list in team_grouper.list|dictsort:"sport.sport" %}
                    <li><a href="{{ team_list.season.season_start_date.year }}/{{ team_list.sport.sport_slug }}/">{{ team_list.sport }} {% if team_list.total_wins > 0 or team_list.total_losses > 0 %}({{ team_list.total_wins }}-{{ team_list.total_losses }}){% endif %}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

which produces this output:

[image: School years with incorrect ordering]

As you can see, the ordering of the school year is not ideal. The data appears this way in the database:

```
 id | school_year 
----+-------------
  1 | 2010-2011
  2 | 2009-2010
  3 | 2011-2012
```

I would like to re-order the results by year. In SQL, this would be expressed this way:

```
select * from seasons_schoolyear order by substring(school_year from 1 for 4);
```

with the following result:

```
 id | school_year 
----+-------------
  2 | 2009-2010
  1 | 2010-2011
  3 | 2011-2012
```

Is there a way to achieve this ordering either in the statement that creates the queryset:

```
teams_at_school = Team.objects.filter(school=team).order_by('season__school_year')
```

or in the template's `regroup` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Add dictsort to your regroup tag like this: `{% regroup teams_at_school|dictsort:"school_year" by season.school_year as teams %}` and remove dict sorting of *teams* in below *for* tag.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I implemented your suggestion like this (since `school_year` is a property of the foreign-key-related object `Season` rather than a property of `Team`): `{% regroup teams_at_school|dictsort:"season.school_year" by season.school_year as teams %}`. This does not appear to reorder the teams, but strangely, it causes a duplication of two of the school years. Instead of the three school years listed above, I now have five (with two duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extra queryset to create the value you need to order by, for example:

```
Team.objects.filter(school=team).select_related(depth=1)
    extra(select={"first_year":"SUBSTRING(yourmodule_school.year from 1 for 4)"}).
    order_by("-first_year")
```

Where yourmodule_school should be a table in your database which has to have a foreign key on Team.

You can check the query is doing what you expect using importing django.db.connection and doing a connection.queries, it would do the joins thanks to the select_related(depth=1). Another way of doing this without some unnecessary joins if you have more than one foreign key on the module would be to do a SELECT query on the extra field like this:

```
Team.objects.filter(school=team).
    extra(select={"first_year":"SELECT SUBSTRING(year from 1 for 4)
    FROM yourmodule_school WHERE id=school_id"}).
    order_by("-first_year")
```

where school_id should be a foreign key named school on your team class.

That way the query creates a new value for the select which can be used for ordering.  [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) is the documentation of extra() just in case.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, `school_year` is a field in the Season model, which is associated with the Team model as a foreign key. Is there a way to use `.extra()` with foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

With a workable server-side solution not forthcoming, I resorted to a client side solution, reordering the list via jQuery:

```
$( "#sport-picker > li.first" ).after( $( "#sport-picker" ).find( "li > span:contains('2011-2012')" ).parent() );
```